# unable to install feature in Liberty Profile 16.0.0.3

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I am trying to install the feature jsp-2.2 feature in Liberty Profile (Java EE 7 Web Profile) 16.0.0.3 using command below:

```
installUtility install jsp-2.2
```

but I am getting below error:

```
CWWKF1286E: The com.ibm.websphere.appserver.javax.el-2.2 feature cannot be downloaded from the IBM WebSphere Liberty Repository. See the problem determination information on the WebSphere Application Server Support web page.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it right now (using wlp-webProfile7-16.0.0.3) it worked.  Here's the CLI output:

---

Select [1] I Agree, or [2] I do not Agree:  1

Step 1 of 5: Downloading servlet-3.0 ...
Step 2 of 5: Installing servlet-3.0 ...
Step 3 of 5: Downloading jsp-2.2 ...
Step 4 of 5: Installing jsp-2.2 ...
Step 5 of 5: Cleaning up temporary files ...

All assets were successfully installed.

Start product validation...
Product validation completed successfully.

---

Can you try again?  Maybe the repository was temporarily down.  If still doesn't work, which JDK are you using?

Comment: May be the repo was down...it worked for me too now.